# Need help with question regarding orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthonormal

Let v1=(3/√14, 1/√14, -2/√14), v2= (1/√3,-1/√3,1/√3), v3=(1/√42,5/√42,4/√42) and its also known that the set {v1,v2,v3} is an orthonormal basis of R3. Write the vector u=(100,-200,300) as a linear combination of v1,v2,v3.

I am so lost in changing basis relatively for a vector, and i would appreciate any sort of tip or instructions on about doing this sort of question.

Comment: I suspect the second component of your vector $v_3$ should be $5/\sqrt{42}$ rather than $5/\sqrt{43}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the change of basis formula: $u^*_i = \alpha_{ij} u_i$, where $\alpha_{ij} = v_i \cdot \hat{e}_j$, where the $\hat{e}_j$ are the standard basis vectors of $R^3$.

So $\alpha_{ij} u_i$ in this case is just
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{14}} & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{14}} & \dfrac{-2}{\sqrt{14}} \\
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{3}} & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{42}} & \dfrac{5}{\sqrt{42}} & \dfrac{4}{\sqrt{42}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
100 \\
-200 \\
300
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which equals
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{-500}{\sqrt{14}} \\
\dfrac{600}{\sqrt{3}} \\
\dfrac{300}{\sqrt{42}} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The ith row of this resulting column vector is $u^*_i$, the ith component of $u$ after the change of basis, so the vector $u$ would be the linear combination 
$u^*_1 (\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{14}} , \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{14}} , \dfrac{-2}{\sqrt{14}}) + \ldots $ etc.

Comment: Ahh! It makes alot of sense now geometrically! Thanks alot:)